# It is right thing to ignore warning in proguard android

Tags: java, android, proguard

I started learning **Proguard** for android. After a bit of reading, i start trying to use in my project. When i start generating release build, i see lots of warnings and notes in android studio terminal. I know it totally depends on my code base and third party libraries i used.

My Questions

- **I don't understand what these warning trying to say?** But build will fail for sure and will not able to generate apk file.
- Surprisingly adding `-dontwarn packagename*` will ignore these warnings but again not sure it is safe thing to do. **Is it always feasible to simply ignore those warning just by adding `-dontwarn`** ?

> **-dontwarn [class_filter]**
>
> Specifies not to warn about unresolved references and other important problems at all. The optional filter is
>   a regular expression; ProGuard doesn't print warnings about classes
>   with matching names. Ignoring warnings can be dangerous. For instance,
>   if the unresolved classes or class members are indeed required for
>   processing, the processed code will not function properly. *Only use
>   this option if you know what you're doing!*

Well definitely at this point, i don't really know what i am doing. I would be very much appreciate if you could help me understand ;-) .

#### Retrofit2 warnings from my current project

> Warning: retrofit2.OkHttpCall: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.GuardedBy
>
> Warning: retrofit2.OkHttpCall:can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.GuardedBy
>
> Warning: retrofit2.OkHttpCall: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.GuardedBy

Simply turn off above warning by adding this line in **proguard-rules.pro**

> -dontwarn retrofit2.**

Comment: What exactly you want?,are suggesting some thing or asking some thing please clear it.

Comment: - I don't understand what these warning trying to say?
- Is it always feasible to simply ignore those warning just by adding `-dontwarn`

Answer (score 5):

So basically the Proguard maps your code or performs the code **obfuscation**, **shrinking**, **optimization** removes unused code...etc while performing the same, sometimes it finds many classes which are used either in import statement or some where else but those class are not actually present inside the package, so it generates the warnings as Proguard is not able to get the reference for some classes. Optimization operates with Java bytecode, though, and since Android runs on Dalvik bytecode which is converted from Java bytecode, some optimizations won't work so well. So you should be careful there.

So in **dont warn** we simply ignores those files to go through the proguard operations.
Hope this is enough information for you.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil, how it is possible for classes are that are declared and not exist ? Those missing classes are removed by Proguard ? And it is safe just to ignore all type of warning in proguard . ?

Comment: Like some classes declared in libs, jar files you are using where proguard is not able to link or find the reference, \*Yes\* it is right to ignore those classes as main use applying the proguard is security of our code, but if the proguard is not able to find them, then no problem.